# Jenkins GIT plugin: passing environment variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-checkout

I'm using git checkout as

```
checkout scmGit(
    branches: [[name: 'stable-3.x']],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin.git']])
```

I need to set an environment variable which should be used in a post-checkout hooks.

I tried with `environment {MY_ENV=1}`, `withEnv(['MY_ENV=1'])`.

But the plugin ignores everything.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure environment credentials or without and configure something like this in checkout.

```
environment {
    ManifestRepoUrl='https://gitgerrit.com/test'
    GitHTTPSCredentials='Gitcreddev'
 }
 checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches:
    [[name: "review"]],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: GitHTTPSCredentials,url: ManifestRepoUrl]]
```

Comment: This is not what I need. I need an env variable to be visible from the post-checkout hook which is executed by the "checkout" plugin.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).